# Problema instalando spyder

Tags: python, unicode

Estoy intentando instalar directamente spyder sin recurrir a algo tipo anaconda o winpy. Para ello, he instalado python 2.7.13 y PyQt4. Con eso instalado he probado a lanzar el comando

```
pip install spyder
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\lvarom~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-qnvhsd\\scandir\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\lvarom~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-exbo4z-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\lvarom~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qnvhsd\scandir\
```

He probado a instalarlo desde un .whl pero con el mismo resultado

¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Sistema operativo?¿Tienes más versiones de Python instaladas?, ¿si es así cual es la que tienes por defecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error relacionado con la codificación de las cadenas de texto.

Python 2.7 no usa unicode por defecto ([leer más](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)) y puede que tu nombre en la ruta (**Á**lvaro) esté dándote errores.

Recomendaciones:

- Utiliza Python 3.x que formatea los strings como unicode y si estás
  empezando es lo recomendado.
- Si no quieres instalar todos los paquetes de Anaconda, tienes [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) que sólo instala Python y para instalar spyder te bastaría con escribir en una ventana de comandos `conda install spyder`. Si te decides a utilizarlo, desinstala primero el Python de windows que tienes para evitar problemas.
- En realidad, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) es un IDE con versión community gratuita y mucho más potente/estable/maduro que Spyder. La curva de aprendizaje es un poco más elevada pero está muy bien documentado y vale la pena.